# Binding to jQuery :input is not firing event

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code that is not working when I run it. Kindly tell me what is missing or where I went wrong.

```
$(':input').bind('keypress keydown keyup change', function() {
    var acho = parseFloat($(':input[name="acho"]').val(),10),
        alto = parseFloat($(':input[name="alto"]').val(),10),
        matl = parseFloat($(':input[name="material"]').val(),10);
        cat = parseFloat($(':input[name="category"]').val(),10);

    var v = '';

    if (!isNaN(acho) && !isNaN(alto) && !isNaN(matl)){
        v = cat*(matl / 100) / ((alto / 100) * (acho / 100));
    }

    $(':input[name="ml"]').val(v.toString());

​});​
```

Comment: Your title provides no information about the question.

Comment: Could you perhaps make a jsFiddle.net? I'm not sure what this code is trying to accomplish

Comment: `parseFloat` doesn't take a radix parameter.

Comment: @JonathanWood yes and the question itself doesn't say much more.

Comment: -1 for not saying HOW it's not working. dystroy's got the answer below, but it's still a horribly phrased question. +1 for dystroy figuring it out from the utter lack of detail the OP's given.

Comment: @Vic please rephrase your question, editing the title and question to include what is occurring and what you expect to occur.

Comment: How are you calling this code? Is it after it is rendered?

Comment: @NathanKoop what makes you think the OP's problem is that the event isn't firing (per your edit to the question title) ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with your variable definitions:

```
matl = parseFloat($(':input[name="material"]').val(),10);
```

This line should have a comma after it, b/c of the subsequent variable assignment. And I would throw `v` in just for good measure.

```
var acho = parseFloat($(':input[name="acho"]').val()),
    alto = parseFloat($(':input[name="alto"]').val()),
    matl = parseFloat($(':input[name="material"]').val()),
    cat = parseFloat($(':input[name="category"]').val()),
    v = '';
```

(Also removed invalid radix parameter from `parseFloat`)

Corrected code:

```
$(':input').bind('keypress keydown keyup change', function() {
    var acho = parseFloat($(':input[name="acho"]').val()),
        alto = parseFloat($(':input[name="alto"]').val()),
        matl = parseFloat($(':input[name="material"]').val()),
        cat = parseFloat($(':input[name="category"]').val()),
        v = '';

    if ( !isNaN(acho) && !isNaN(alto) && !isNaN(matl) ){
        v = cat*(matl / 100) / ((alto / 100) * (acho / 100));
    }

    $(':input[name="ml"]').val( v.toString() );
});
```

Comment: you're correct, but that's not the root problem, it'll just result in `cat` being a global instead of local

Comment: Can you see what I am trying to achieve here, click this link http://jsbin.com/welcome/45107/

Comment: @Vic Yes. Firebug shows an error in your script: `Error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list Line: 29, Column: 60
Source Code:
     matl = parseFloat($(':input[name="material"]').val(),10;` You are missing the closing paren and need to remove the radix

Comment: Please check the whole codes here http://jsbin.com/welcome/45107/edit and the javascript part is the problem.

Comment: Paste your JS into JSLint: http://jslint.com/

Comment: @Vic I have updated my answer with corrected code, but you should checkout that JSLint link I posted, as it would've shown you the problem.

Comment: @KevinBoucher you code is not working, I'm trying to check the JSLint link

Answer (score 0):

Your code *mostly* works:

1. ensure it's in a `document.ready` handler
2. remove the `10` radix parameter from `parseFloat` - it's not supported
3. don't register on the `keyXXX` functions - some of them are called before the pressed key has been added to the input's value
4. use HTML5's `input` event (and `change`) instead
5. don't forget to test `cat` for `isNaN`  [ah, it's a dropdown - never mind]
6. make sure every `var` is properly declared

My working version with minimal modifications is at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/6hNQ2/ and a cleaned up version:

```
$(':input').bind('input change', function() {

    // don't repeat yourself - also strips whitespace
    function val(f) {
        var $el = $(':input[name="' + f + '"]');
        return parseFloat($.trim($el.val()));
    }

    var acho = val('acho'),
        alto = val('alto'),
        matl = val('material'),
        cat = val('category');

    if (isNaN(acho) || isNaN(alto) || isNaN(matl)) {
        return;
    }

    var v = cat * (matl / 100) / ((alto / 100) * (acho / 100));
    $(':input[name="ml"]').val(v);
});​
```

at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/4Xw3D/

Comment: my code also works on jsfiddle.net by not other html. check my jsfiddle code http://jsfiddle.net/LhyuF/134/ . I need it to work in my html page too

Comment: @Vic you didn't use a `document.ready` handler - jsfiddle wraps your code in one automatically so it's very common for code to work there but not work on your own site.

Comment: Hi @Alnitak can you paste your full code so that i see why mine is still not working despite the correction

Comment: I already did - the only thing you need is to wrap the whole code in `$(document).ready(function() { ... }` where `...` is the code above.